# carry data between different spreadsheets googleSpreadSheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```js
/* 
 **** Move a row onEdit determined by a specific Cell value***
 */
 
// Names of sheets
var sourceSheet = "datasource"
var destinationSheet = "datadestiny"
 
/* col: the column to watch,  
 * changeVal: what value you want to change,
 * del: do you want to delete after the change?
 */
var check = {
  "col":22,
  "changeVal": "OK",
  "del": true
  };
 
/* What you want to paste into the other sheet.
 * start: start column
 * cols: how many columns you want to copy
 */
var pasteRange = {
  "start": 1, 
  "cols": 2
  };
 
 
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  
  if(sheet.getName() === sourceSheet){
    
    //Get active cell
    var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
    var cellCol = cell.getColumn();
    var cellRow = cell.getRow(); 
    
    if(cellCol === check.col){
      if(cell.getValue() === check.changeVal){
        
        //Select the range you want to export
        var exportRange = sheet.getRange(cellRow,pasteRange.start,1,pasteRange.cols);
        
        
        //Select the past destination
        var dest = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1sMenz31IMkCsa20ORue09EVMKyNujHCqgnM6C5HD_yo');

        var pasteDestination = dest.getSheetByName(destinationSheet);
        var pasteEmptyBottomRow = pasteDestination.getLastRow() + 1;
       
        //Copy the row to the new destination
        exportRange.copyTo(pasteDestination.getRange(pasteEmptyBottomRow,1),
                           SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES);
        

        //If delete is true delete after copying
        if(check.del){
          sheet.deleteRow(cellRow);
        };
      };
    };
  };
 };
```

I need some help, i am trying to transport data from one spreadsheet to another googleSpreadSheets spreadsheet

spreadsheet - source - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ki_EKHYVifJzm3pWnSs_GlnJPrIzN2bEZHQmexPgF_M/edit#gid=0

spreadsheet - destiny - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sMenz31IMkCsa20ORue09EVMKyNujHCqgnM6C5HD_yo/edit#gid=0

the onEdit() function cannot transport the data.

Comment: Can I ask you about `the onEdit() function cannot transport the data.`? If an error occurs, please show it. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#execution_transcript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

The first problem is that you need an installable trigger.  You can create it manually or with software. Your choice.  The second problem is that the copy to only works on the same spreadsheet.  So you can use getValues() and setValues() instead as I have done below:

```
function testonEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='datasource') {
    if(e.range.columnStart==22 && e.value=="OK"){
      var dss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('11f9yyZZs5Ret6YoXinvne0eCXWWaXdj12t6MnrT43vM');
      var dsh=dss.getSheetByName('datadestiny');
      var v=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,2).getValues();
      dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow(),1,v.length,v[0].length).setValues(v);
      sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
    }
  }
}
```

I've modified the code a bit to suit my testing.  I try to keep the onEdit() functions as light as possible because you want them to be a fast as possible because you only have 30 seconds to get them done.

Comment: your script didn't work, I copied and pasted its function (adjusting openById)

Comment: @Fragosojp You need to add it as an installable trigger under `Edit > Current project's triggers`, click `+ Add Trigger` in the bottom right and set up how often you want it to run.

Comment: I presume you want to select an onEdit style of trigger not a timebased.

Comment: The script has been tested it works if you know how to install it.

Comment: I understand now, how triggers work, one more thing instead of data being transferred on the same line is always inserting a line below, in the destiny worksheet? I tried with getLastRow but I couldn't ...

Comment: It now adds it to the last row in `dsh`

Comment: I need one more help in the script, it works very well, but I realized that when I have an EX value: '21, when transporting this value it puts only 21, how to make the script transport exactly the same value with the '21?

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: By the way your links are not public

Comment: I will allow access to spreadsheets

Source worksheet: A2 has the value of '26 / 09/2019 15:26.
when this value is transposed to the destiny spreadsheet the value is 26/09/2019 15:26:00, i need it to carry exactly the '26 / 09/2019 15:26 with this character in front of the date